# difference between $ and $() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Could someone take the effort to explain me the difference between `$` and `$()` in jquery?

I know `$()` is shorthand form of `$jQuery()` which takes any DOM element and turns it into a jQuery object.

But what I am not sure of is what is `$` and how different is it from `$()`. Kindly enlighten me.

Thanks heaps,
Chaitanya

Comment: $ and jQuery both point to the window.jQuery object.

Comment: check this [difference-between-these-two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609133/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`$` is a *function* that can be called - `$()`.

The behaviour of `$()` varies immensely depending on the parameters supplied, although all examples below will *return* a `jQuery` object.  It can:

1. register a `document.ready` handler - `$(myfunc)`
2. act as a selector    - `$('#myid')`
3. construct elements   - `$('<div>')`
4. return an empty object - `$()`

`$` is also an *object* that contains various utility functions `$.each`, etc as *properties* of that object.  In this context, it acts like a *namespace* for those functions.

Answer (score 6):

`$ = jQuery` - This is the jQuery object which is used for the jQuery Utilies it contains such as `$.Ajax()` or `$.each()` Thus `var j = $;` will assign the jquery prototype into the variable `j`.

$() = `jQuery()` - This is a function called from the root jQuery object that is used convert DOM elements to jQuery Objects or get jQuery objects using selectors

Comment: So, can I think of $ as jQuery alias and hence $() is jQuery function?

Comment: @chaitanya-msv Yes

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps and add on to the other posts `:)`

- `$`  = is a a valid javascript object/identifier.
- `$()` = calling $() creates an empty jQuery object.

*jQuery() — which can also be written as $() — searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these elements:*

**Official Document** [Please read docs here (click me)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) I would highly recommend that you should read this document.

Your question is mix of 2 sperate questions please see below:

- [What is the meaning of "$" sign in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)
- [Can someone explain what = $(); means in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107888/can-someone-explain-what-means-in-jquery)

Comment: here we go again.... ;-)  please 1.  trim those quotes to only include _relevant_ text   2. provide new useful content, not just links to other answers.  Those links could be _comments_, not an answer...

Comment: @Alnitak Any suggestions to improve please! :-) With your experience I am honored if you can mentor, no kidding at all, I won't call you bruv this time sorry for that :) **a** I will remove spaces, **b** anything extra of some kind ?

Comment: oh, and use the blockquote `>` character, not code indent! ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak Cool made few changes, thank-you! Stackoverflow and guys like you make is awesomeness :P to be around! cheers! feel free to let me know I am happy to put extra work and improve anything or take yur suggestion onboard!

Answer (score 2):

If i create a function:

function my_function() {
       alert('my_function');
       return(33)
   }

`my_function` is a variable that contains a function.
`my_function()` is the result of the function call.

You would use the function call `my_function()` to execute the instructions in the function and/or to get the returned result into a variable `var my_var = my_function();`.

You would use the variable name of the function in order to pass it to another function as a parameter such as `$('a').click(my_function);`

Since in JavaScript variables can be of any kind that includes scalar (literal values), arrays, objects and functions.

Now taking that idea and building on it:

`$` is just a variable name just as `jQuery` is just a variable name.

As it so happens this variable *contains* a function which means that `$()` or `jQuery()` executes what ever instructions are present in the function body `$`.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a reference to the jQuery namespace, via which you can access its static methods (e.g. `ajax`, `each` etc), while `$()` calls a function that either registers a DOM-ready callback (if a function is passed to it) or returns elements from the DOM (if a selector string or element is passed to it).

Incidentally, `$` is short-hand for `jQuery`, not `$jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, everything is data, this includes function. As a contrived example:

```
function test() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

For this example, `test()` is the invocation of the function. Simply using `test` is like using a variable which allows you to do something like:

```
var t = test;
t();
```

Which then causes `t` to have the same data/functionality as `test`.

This then allows you to do something like a closure:

```
function closure() {
  var i = 0;
  function inner() {
    i++;
    console.log(i);
  }

  return inner;
}
```

Since a function is just some data, we can return it and then invoke it. So you would then write something like:

```
var t = closure();
t(); // prints '1'
t(); // prints '2'
```

Among other benefits, doing this allows you to keep your namespace a bit less cluttered.

To directly answer your question, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery` which was made by doing:

```
function jQuery() { /* Lots of code */ }
$ = jQuery;
```